# Matching a drawn card to its gif in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm creating a card game and I'm having trouble getting a card gif to display. A card is drawn from an 52 card deck arraylist, and I then need to match that drawn card with the similarly named gif in an arraylist of card gifs, to display the gif on a card GUI. I have put my game, card, deck and graphical class below to give you an idea of how my program is working:

Card -

```js
    package uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards;

 public class Card {
 public String number;
 public String suit;

 public Card(String n, String s) {
  number = n;
  suit = s;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return number + suit;
 }

}
```

Game -

```js
     import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.Card;
import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.gui.TheFrame;

public class Game {

 private Scanner scan;
 private Deck deck;
 private TheFrame frame;
 private ArrayList<Card> onTable = new ArrayList<Card>();

 public Game() {
  frame = new TheFrame();
  deck = new Deck();
  try {
   deck.buildDeck();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Error reading in deck...");
   System.exit(-1);
  }

 }

 private void runMenu() throws IOException {

  String response;
  do {
   printMenu();
   System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
   scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   response = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
   switch (response) {
   case "1":
    PrintDeck();
    break;
   case "2":
    ShuffleCards();
    break;
   case "3":
    DealCard();
    break;
   case "4":
    MoveToPrevious();
    break;
   case "5":
    Move2PilesBack();
    break;
   case "6":
    AmalgamateInMiddle();
    break;
   case "7":
    PlayforMe();
    break;
   case "8":
    ShowLowScores();
   case "Q":
    break;
   default:
    System.out.println("Try again");

   }
   drawCards();

  } while (!(response.equals("Q")));
 }

 private void ShowLowScores() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void PlayforMe() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void AmalgamateInMiddle() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void Move2PilesBack() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void MoveToPrevious() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void DealCard() {
  Card c = deck.removeTopCard();

  System.out.println(c);
 }

 private void ShuffleCards() {

  deck.shuffle();

 }

 private void drawCards() {
  ArrayList<String> visibleCards = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (Card card : onTable) {
   visibleCards.add(card.number + card.suit + ".gif");
    
  }
   
  frame.cardDisplay(visibleCards);
   
 }

 private void PrintDeck() throws IOException {
  for (Card card : deck.getDeck()) {
   System.out.println(card);
  }

 }

 private void printMenu() {

  System.out.println("1 -  Print the pack ");
  System.out.println("2 -  Shuffle");
  System.out.println("3 -  Deal a card");
  System.out.println("4 -  Move last pile onto previous one");
  System.out.println("5 -  Move last pile back over two piles");
  System.out.println("6 -  Amalgamate piles in the middle");
  System.out.println("7 -  Play for me");
  System.out.println("8 -  Show low scores");
  System.out.println("q - Quit");

 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  System.out.println("****Welcome to patience is virtue****");
  Game cardsgame = new Game();
  cardsgame.runMenu();
  System.out.println("****Thanks for playing****");
 }
}
```

Deck -

```js
  

  import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.Card;

public class Deck {
 private ArrayList<Card> cards;

 public Deck() {
  cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
 }

 public void buildDeck() throws IOException {

  List<String> cardLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("cards.txt"));
  for (int i = 0; i < cardLines.size(); i += 2) {
   // System.out.println()
   cards.add(new Card(cardLines.get(i), cardLines.get(i + 1)));

  }
 }

 public Card removeTopCard() {
  return cards.remove(0);
 }

 public List<Card> getDeck() {
  return cards;
 }

 public void shuffle() {
  Collections.shuffle(cards);
  System.out.println(cards);
 }

}
```

Graphical (frame) class -

```js
     package uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.Card;
 
public class TheFrame extends JFrame {

 public static boolean paintComponent;
 private ThePanel canvas;

 /**
  * The constructor creates a Frame ready to display the cards
  */
 public TheFrame() {

  // Calls the constructor in the JFrame superclass passing up the name to 
  // display in the title
  super("Becky's Patience");
  
  // When you click on the close window button the window will be closed
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  
  // This has North, East, South, West and Center positions for components
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  // This is what we will draw on (see the inner class below)
  canvas = new ThePanel(null);
  setSize(700, 300);
  this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  setVisible(true); // Display the window
 }

 /**
  * Displays all cards
  * 
  * @param cards
  *            an arraylist of strings of the form 3h.gif for 3 of hearts
  */
 /*public void cardDisplay(ArrayList<String> cards) {
  canvas.cardDisplay(cards);
 }*/
 
 /**
  * Call before cardDisplay at end of game (takes away the unused pile)
  */
 public void allDone() {
  canvas.allDone();
 }

 // /////////////////////////////////////////////////

 /*
  * This is an example of an inner class (like Russian dolls)
  * It private so can only be seen by the outer class. It's part
  * of the implementation of TheFrame. Because it extends JPanel we
  * can draw on it
  */
 
 Map<Card, Image> loadCards(ArrayList<Card> cards)
    {
       Map<Card, Image> cardImages = new HashMap<>();
       for (Card card : cards) 
       {
            String file = "cards/" + card.number + card.suit + ".gif";
            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
            cardImages.put(card, image);
       }
       return cardImages;
    }
 
 private class ThePanel extends JPanel {
  private Map<Card, Image> cardImages;
     private ArrayList<Card> currentCardDisplayed;
     private boolean done;

     private ThePanel(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
       setBackground(Color.cyan);
       done = false;
       cardImages = loadCards(cards);
  }

  private void cardDisplay(ArrayList<String> c) {
   cards = c;
   repaint();
  }

  private void allDone() {
   done = true;
  }

  /**
   * This is called automatically by Java when it want to draw this panel.
   * So we have to put our drawing command in here. 
   * @param g Is the graphics object on which we draw.
   */
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   // Always do this. It's giving the JPanel superclass a change to
   // paint its parts before we paint ours. E.g. we don't draw the
   // edge of the window, one of the super-classes does that.
   super.paintComponent(g);
   int x = 20;
   int y = 50;
   // Loop through all the cards get each image in turn
   for (Card card: currentCardDisplayed) {
       g.drawImage(cardImages.get(card), x, y, 70, 100, this);
    x += 72;  // The x position is moved on in order to position the next card
              // This could be improved by having a horizontal scroll bar
   }
   if (!done) {
    // Draws the face-down top card of our pack of cards
    String file = "cards/b.gif";
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
    g.drawImage(image, 100, 152, 70, 100, this);
   }
  }
 } // ThePanel inner class
```

Here is what the gifs look like in their folder, which is an arraylist in my graphical class :
[image: Here is what the gifs look like in their folder, which is an arraylist in my graphical class :]

Here is what the drawn card looks like after the textual card arraylist has been shuffled: 
[image: Here is what the drawn card looks like after the textual card arraylist has been shuffled:]

The arrayList of card gifs (which contains all 52 gifs for the cards) is in the graphical class and my arrayList that contains the deck of cards in textual form (that I've imported from a textfile) is in deck. The names of the gifs in the gif arraylist are the same as the card names in my textual card arraylist (for example, 3h.gif is 3h in my card arraylist), so I believe I can use a .equals statement to match the card that has been drawn to the gif.

Any help offered on how I could do this would be great, I have boldened the areas that are important to help show what I mean, Thanks for any help :)!

UPDATE: I'm experiencing some errors in the Game and TheFrame classes. Where it says 'cards' under the card display in TheFrame it's saying it doesn't exsis. It's also saying 'image' can't be resolved to a variable in the Paint component method. In game It's aying that CardDisplay in the drawCards method is "undefined for the type TheFrame".
If anyone could help with these errors that would be brilliant :)!

Comment: I didn't read all that, but it sounds like you want a map. You should make your question shorter and more to-the-point.

Comment: I don't know how to make it shorter without not showing all my code, as people need to see what's going on , also, what's a map? How and where can it be used in my code, because this is for an assignment and we got provided with one class, the graphical (frame) one.

Comment: Your question is more of the conceptual sort, so if you phrase it well you don't need any code at all. Since I'm guessing that's hard in this case, some code might help, but showing your entire project is not the way to go. Maps are also known as associative arrays or dictionaries. Look them up. E.g. HashMap in java.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but if I show code and images it's easier for people to help, because I'm not exactly that knowledgable when it comes to code so find it hard getting my questions across to more experienced coders. And I'll look up HashMap, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is not to keep an `ArrayList <String> cards` in your `ThePanel`. Instead you want to load the Image objects when you build the panel, and keep them in a map. This method will load the map for you:

```
   void loadCards(ArrayList<Card> cards)
   {
      Map<Card, Image> cardImages = new HashMap<>();
      for (Card card : cards) 
      {
           String file = "cards/" + card.number + card.suit + ".gif";
           image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
           cardImages.put(card, image);
      }
      return cardImages;
   }
```

Store the result of this method in your ThePanel:

```
private class ThePanel extends JPanel {
    private Map<Card, Image> cardImages;
    private ArrayList<Card> currentCardDisplayed;
    private boolean done;

    private ThePanel(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
      setBackground(Color.cyan);
      done = false;
      cardImages = loadCards(cards);
    }
```

Then in your repaint, you can do something like:

```
  for (Card card: currentCardDisplayed) {
    g.drawImage(cardImages.get(card), x, y, 70, 100, this);
    ....
  }
```

Finally, it's probably a good idea to implement Card.equals and Card.hashCode, now that you will be using a map!

Comment: What class would I put loadCards in, TheFrame?, because its currently asking me to create a Card class when I put in in theFrame class, even though I already have a Card class (it may be because TheFrame is using a different package.

Comment: You don't jave to make a new Card class. Use your existing one, even if it's in a different package. You can use "import" for that. There's no rule saying you can only communicate across packages using Strings... It's ok for the graphic classes to know about the Card class, which is a very basic data structure in your project.

Comment: Sicne loadCards is used only by ThePanel, I would put it there.

Comment: I've updated the code and listed some problem I've had, if you can help with anything :).

Comment: These new questions aren't really related to the old one. By changing the code you made the answer basically unrelated to your question. If you have a new question you should post it as a new question.

Comment: It is also polite to accept an answer if it helped you :-)